What is the best way to adapt a larger connector when the insertion holes on the PCB do not match?
Good day, everyone. I have a Type-C connector on a device that is much larger than the micro USB connector I had previously. The insertion legs do not align with the holes on the PCB, and since it is on the edge of the board (it is a charging port), there is not much room to maneuver. The connector is almost above some SMD transistors, which I plan to cover with Kapton tape to isolate them and avoid any issues.
I have also considered soldering a couple of wires to the legs of the connector, passing them through the holes, and soldering them on the other side, then adding a little silicone to ensure it does not move. However, I am concerned that repeated connecting and disconnecting of the charger might cause the connector to come loose.
What do you recommend? I would appreciate any advice.
Thanks in advance.
P.S. Apologies for any errors in my English; I am learning the language.



Have your considered a USB-c to micro USB adapter, instead of modifying the pcb?

Do you realise that a USB-C connector isn't a functional replacement for a Micro USB? What do you plan to use it for?

Your idea of soldering wire between the new connector and the existing circuit board should work fine.  You need to make the connector mechanically stable, though, and one easy way to do that is to firmly attach it to the enclosure (not the circuit board) with something like epoxy or super glue.
Another option is to build a very small circuit board that has your old connector's footprint on one side and your new connector's footprint on the other.  You would solder this board onto your existing circuit board, then solder your new connector on top.  For an example of what I'm talking about, you can look at the photos of this USB-C converter board designed to replace the non-standard charging port on a Nintendo DS console.  Something like this is much more mechanically stable, but you have to have room for the interposer board.

Thank you for responding. Since the connector is almost above the SMD components (capacitors, resistors), could I cover them with Kapton tape or silicone to avoid problems, or would that be a bad idea?

How can you be sure that it will work fine to put the usb connector on wires? If it's supposed to support USB2.0 HS at 480Mb/s I don't think flying wires all loosey goosey will work fine.

@MrGerber OP said that this was only a charging port, so the integrity of the data connection doesn't really matter. It's a USB2 connection so it'll charge off the power lines alone and not need to negotiate with the USB charger.

@condor12 You should definitely insulate them with something.  You might find it easier to wrap the connector with tape. You can do that before you install the connector, when you still have room to work.  That way you'll be protected no matter what it comes in contact with. Kapton tape works fairly well but it's notorious for breaking. If the connector is expected to move around at all, even a little bit, you might want something more durable like a small piece of electrical tape.
